# msi.dll missing because of renaming

Tags: windows-xp, dll

I have renamed `msi.dll` to `msi.old`. But now this is giving error, because of this I cant able to open microsoft office. now again i want to rename it as `msi.dll`.

But I don't know the place where it lives. Where is the `msi.dll`? How i can rename it again.

First time renaming what were i did that with help of some notes but i not have them now

I have performed a search on Windows (search string was *.old and msi) but this did not located msi.old

Comment: @yeah i have searched but not locate it,thats why i am asking question here

Comment: @DaveRook   *.old

Comment: yeah that also checked

Comment: Try to [repair Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924611) first. If that doesn't help, uninstall and reinstall as Dave suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places this could be, on my PC a search for msi.dll returned 2 locations:

c:\windows\system32
c:\windows\servicepackfiles\i386

However, if you have named it msi.old, you could try to search for it on your machine? Click start -> Search.

Type in msi.old and search for it! Or, based upon your comments, search for msi. (include the period ".").

Worse case, re-install the program.